# VSTS - Run Console Application instead of Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs, azure-devops, integration-testing

I'm having trouble finding documentation on how to do this.  I have a Class Library project and a Unit Test Project.  The Unit Test project tests units of functional code.  Amazing, I know.  But I also have a Console Application to perform special Integration Tests.

Granted, I could use some frameworks, or even another "Unit Test" project, where I'm not really writing Unit Tests, but hitting third party APIs and such.  All I'd have to do is NAME the project "Integration Tests".  That's all fine and well, but that's not this question.

My question is, how can I get VSTS to RUN my Console Application and retrieve the output as the Test Results.  In running my Console Application, it will perform some integration testing, and output something (I don't care what) to indicate either failure(s), or success.

On Fail or Success, I want VSTS to act just as it would for a Unit Test run.

In response to comments for **why**: Because I like to push the limits of systems and understand all of my options.  Also because I don't let Microsoft control me even though I use their products.  So even though I don't plan to put this into production at this moment, I want to know the measure of friction of this solution so I can compare it against other frictions.